# Significant number and Measurement resolution

Tags: conventions, measurements, error-analysis

It would be kind if anybody could explain how many significant numbers do we have in 0.00034 if the resolution is 0.001? Without the special mention of "the resolution" my answer was 2, But I can't quite understand it after this clause. Also, it is an example mentioned in one of the Wikipedia articles on significant numbers (I don't how to cite it here, so I am attaching the link for the same webpage in the end). There the answer is <0.00034 has 4 significant zeros if the resolution is 0.001. (3 and 4 are beyond the resolution so are not significant.)>
I don't get this explanation.
Here's an inline link to that Wikipedia page [Significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#cite_note-1).

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 2):

No wonder you do not get it; if the resolution is 0.001, how did they get 0.00034 in the first place?
The measurement beyond the resolution does not make sense. It's like trying to measure the wavelength of a green ray with a ruler.  The result of such measurement is 0.000 and the only conclusion is that one should use a better tool or a better method in that case.  Poor choice of measurement instruments, for example of 0.001 resolution, does not justify "guessing" the measurement of 0.00034.

Comment: Thank you I get it. However, I am still kind of unclear with the resolution and significant figures(both combined ). What I could comprehend is, if we have a regular meter scale that has its maximum resolution to 0.001 m then we must have 4 significant digits in our experiment( 3 for the certain figures of meter, centimeter, and millimeter and the last one for the uncertain yet significant figure). Is it correct? Kindly elucidate, if possible. Thank you so much for taking your time and answering the question.